# OpenCV2 findContours(), contours size not equals to hierarchy size

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to use findContour() to get contours from following picture
[image: 123.jpg]

The code is like this:

```
Mat mat = imread("123.jpg");
    cv::imshow("123.jpg",mat);

    Mat hsv;
    cvtColor(mat,hsv,COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    Mat dst;
    inRange(hsv,Scalar(0,0,49),Scalar(47,165,111),dst);
    cout<<"dst channels:"<<dst.channels()<<endl;

    int c0=0,c255=0,other=0;
    for(int i=0;i<dst.rows;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<dst.cols;j++){
            int v = dst.at<uchar>(i,j);
            if(v == 0){
                c0++;
            }else if(v == 255){
                c255++;
            }else{
                other++;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<"0 count:"<<c0<<",255 count:"<<c255<<",other value count:"<<other<<endl;

    cv::erode(dst,dst,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(1,1),6);
    cv::dilate(dst,dst,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(1,1),6);

    cv::medianBlur(dst,dst,15);
    cv::imshow("inRange",dst);

    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
    Mat temp;
    dst.copyTo(temp);

    findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy,CV_RETR_EXTERNAL,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    cout<<"contours size:"<<contours.size()<<endl;
    cout<<"hierarchy size:"<<hierarchy.size()<<endl;

    for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {
        cout<<"hierarchy at:"<<index<<","<<hierarchy[index]<<endl;
        cv::drawContours(mat,contours,index,Scalar(120,255,0));
    }

    cv::imshow("contours",mat);

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
```

the binary image is like this:
[image: inRange]

the final contour image is like this:
[image: contours]

The log printed in console window is like this:
[image]

I don't know why contours size is smaller than hierarchy size. in fact, there should be three "EXTERNAL" shapes. seems missed one shape in  output contours. this issue trapped me for a day and i'm going to be crazy now...anybody knows why there are only two elements in contours ?did i do something wrong?

Comment: AFAIK when you called findContours() with CV_RETR_EXTERNAL parameter hierarchy is meaningless

Answer (score 2):

This works as expected for me:

```
contours size:3
hierarchy size:3 
hierarchy at:0,[1, -1, -1, -1]
hierarchy at:1,[2, 0, -1, -1]
hierarchy at:2,[-1, 1, -1, -1]
```

[image]

Possible problems in your code are:

- `dst` may be incorrectly initialized
- `dst` may not be binary, i.e. can have values different from `0` and `255`

Code:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Load image
    Mat3b img = imread("path_to_image");

    // Convert to grayscale
    Mat1b bin;
    cvtColor(img, bin, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    // Binarize (remove jpeg artifacts)
    bin = bin > 100;

    vector< vector<Point> > contours;
    vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;

    findContours(bin.clone(), contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

    cout << "contours size:" << contours.size() << endl;
    cout << "hierarchy size:" << hierarchy.size() << endl;

    for (int index = 0; index >= 0; index = hierarchy[index][0]) {
        cout << "hierarchy at:" << index << "," << hierarchy[index] << endl;
        cv::drawContours(img, contours, index, Scalar(120, 255, 0), 2);
    }

    imshow("Result", img);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: HI, Miki, thanks for your help.   this is how i init dst:                                 Mat mat =    imread("123.jpg");
 Mat hsv;
 cvtColor(mat,hsv,COLOR_BGR2HSV);

 Mat dst;
 inRange(hsv,Scalar(0,0,49),Scalar(47,165,111),dst);
 cout<<"channels:"<<dst.channels()<<endl;
 for(int i=0;i<dst.rows;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<dst.cols;j++){
   int v = dst.at<char>(i,j);
   if(v !=0 && v != 255){
    cout <<v<<",";  //seems print a lot of -1 in this place
   }
  }
 }
 cv::erode(dst,dst,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(1,1),6);
 cv::dilate(dst,dst,cv::Mat(),cv::Point(1,1),6);
 cv::medianBlur(dst,dst,15);

Comment: Sorry, as i don't know how to format code in comment. thus it looks a little mess, anyway, seems it is because of this reason "dst may not be binary, i.e. can have values different from 0 and 255". i tried to print all “pixel” in dst. there are a lot of "-1". not sure why, can you help to check this?

Comment: Sure, you're not checking it right: `int v = dst.at<uchar>(i,j);`. It's `uchar`, not `char`.

Comment: Also, please post all your relevant code into the question, with proper formatting @Chailie

Comment: OK, i have reformat the code, also uploaded all relevant  picture .plz review it. thanks very much!

Comment: HI,miki, not sure if you are still watching this. if you have any update, plz let me know, thanks very much @Miki

Comment: @Chailie your snippet works as expected for me. Which OpenCV version are you using?

Comment: sorry, i were spending the spring festival in last week. which is supposed as china's biggest festival. i'm using 2.4.10

Answer (score 0):

My VS tool was linked to `..\opencv\build\x64\vc12\lib` and I was experiencing similar issues.

I solved this by changing the link to `..\opencv\build\x86\vc12\lib`

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 7.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11758737)

Comment: it is not a new question. i mean i get this issue for i used 64 bit's lib before ,after i changed to 32 bit's lib, it doesn't have this kind of problem anymore